# Nested responsive iframes turning tiny?

Tags: html, css, iframe

First everything I am doing is on the same domain.  I am lucky that I do not need to deal with origin issues.  Second I have access to everything.

Currently we are playing our elearning modules - Articulate and Captivate via responsive HTML5 via wordpress.

```
<iframe src="https://fxxx.com/tech/2e8615a0-0782-11e5-aaac-06beb8253f3d/multiscreen.html" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"  allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>
```

This code works and allows us to responsively display the content in the users browsers.  Note that I am iframing the Captivate file in this case and note that Captivate is iframing the actual content in the multiscreen.html.  So we have a nested iframe.

I have been asked to move from the full page responsive design and add a template.  The template is basic and is a 100px header on the top (ROW A), the IFRAME (ROW B COL A) and then a playbar (ROW B COL B).  I can do this if I give the iframe a specific height however if I turn the iframe to width or height at 100% it turns tiny.  Like 100px tiny.

I would like the iframe to be as big as possible but sit on one page for the user - and this also has implications on mobile usage.  How can I force the nested iframes to fill the remaining height on the page?

Also our vendor has a tool that displays courses (on same domain) and I may have to have this page iframed in their tool - iframe to the third power.  I would rather it be a css/html solution.

**Note:**  That when I try to used fixed/absolute position and style everything at 100% it sets up right be the video is 100% of the viewport so the 100px header pushes the bottom of the video off of the page.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent CSS measurement unit called,`vw`and `vh` (viewport width and viewport height) might help in your situation.

Replace:`width: 100%` and `height: 100%`

with: `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`

If that doesn't work, try applying `100vw/vh` to `<body>` instead. See this [**ARTICLE**](http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design) for details. If you have problems with the other elements being displaced, try changing `position: fixed` to `position: relative` on the `<iframe>`( or `position: absolute` if you have `position: relative' on``).

Btw, you may have to adjust a little to accommodate for ROW A and ROW B COL B

---